# PhpStorm doesn't match any file I try to find

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

When I press `Ctrl+Shift+N` (Go to File) and start to find any file, I don't get any results. I tried to delete the `.idea` folder, and unfortunately no luck. Do you have any suggestions how to fix this? my PhpStorm version is 10.0.0.1.

**Update** - I tried to open another project, and It still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know exactly what caused this problem, but when I tried to invalidate the cache and restart, it did the work. (File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart)

Comment: the loathsome 'invalidate caches' and restart will become your first reflex as soon as something looks fishy. That and a few voodoo rituals should fix anything Jetbrains does not wish to recognize as a bug. I use it at least 5 times a day.  That being said, Jetbrains products still give me great productivity. You only have to cultivate the reflex that the tool is in error.